# What's causing my long notes to be imported as singles in my rhythm game using MidiFiles and Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I learn from this YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ev0HsmgLScg&pp=ygUWbWFrZSByaHl0aG0gZ2FtZSB1bml0eQ%3D%3D how to makerhythm game using midifile. Suddenly its works using midimaker (lmms), but suddenly there was a problem. When I hold the note in a midimaker, when I import to the unity, its just appear a single notes.

I was trying to configure with making the new script (longNote.cs) when I realized the notes appear one by one (loaded from midi one by one, not all of them)

[image: Here The Example]

This is the line of song manager code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Core;
using Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Interaction;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System;

public class SongManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static SongManager Instance;
    public AudioSource audioSource;
    public Lane[] lanes;
    public float songDelayInSeconds;
    public double marginOfError; // in seconds

    public int inputDelayInMilliseconds;
    

    public string fileLocation;
    public float noteTime;
    public float noteSpawnY;
    public float noteTapY;
    public float noteDespawnY
    {
        get
        {
            return noteTapY - (noteSpawnY - noteTapY);
        }
    }

    public static MidiFile midiFile;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Instance = this;
        if (Application.streamingAssetsPath.StartsWith("http://") || Application.streamingAssetsPath.StartsWith("https://"))
        {
            StartCoroutine(ReadFromWebsite());
        }
        else
        {
            ReadFromFile();
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator ReadFromWebsite()
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + fileLocation))
        {
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.LogError(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                byte[] results = www.downloadHandler.data;
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream(results))
                {
                    midiFile = MidiFile.Read(stream);
                    GetDataFromMidi();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void ReadFromFile()
    {
        midiFile = MidiFile.Read(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + fileLocation);
        GetDataFromMidi();
    }
    public void GetDataFromMidi()
    {
        var notes = midiFile.GetNotes();
        var array = new Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Interaction.Note[notes.Count];
        notes.CopyTo(array, 0);

        foreach (var lane in lanes) lane.SetTimeStamps(array);

        Invoke(nameof(StartSong), songDelayInSeconds);
    }
    public void StartSong()
    {
        audioSource.Play();
    }
    public static double GetAudioSourceTime()
    {
        return (double)Instance.audioSource.timeSamples / Instance.audioSource.clip.frequency;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

This is the line of notes code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Note : MonoBehaviour
{
    double timeInstantiated;
    public float assignedTime;
    void Start()
    {
        timeInstantiated = SongManager.GetAudioSourceTime();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        double timeSinceInstantiated = SongManager.GetAudioSourceTime() - timeInstantiated;
        float t = (float)(timeSinceInstantiated / (SongManager.Instance.noteTime * 2));

        
        if (t > 1)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(Vector3.up * SongManager.Instance.noteSpawnY, Vector3.up * SongManager.Instance.noteDespawnY, t); 
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the line of the lane code

```
using Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Interaction;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Lane : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Melanchall.DryWetMidi.MusicTheory.NoteName noteRestriction;
    public KeyCode input;
    public GameObject notePrefab;
    List<Note> notes = new List<Note>();
    public List<double> timeStamps = new List<double>();

    int spawnIndex = 0;
    int inputIndex = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }
    public void SetTimeStamps(Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Interaction.Note[] array)
    {
        foreach (var note in array)
        {
            if (note.NoteName == noteRestriction)
            {
                var metricTimeSpan = TimeConverter.ConvertTo<MetricTimeSpan>(note.Time, SongManager.midiFile.GetTempoMap());
                timeStamps.Add((double)metricTimeSpan.Minutes * 60f + metricTimeSpan.Seconds + (double)metricTimeSpan.Milliseconds / 1000f);
            }
        }
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (spawnIndex < timeStamps.Count)
        {
            if (SongManager.GetAudioSourceTime() >= timeStamps[spawnIndex] - SongManager.Instance.noteTime)
            {
                var note = Instantiate(notePrefab, transform);
                notes.Add(note.GetComponent<Note>());
                note.GetComponent<Note>().assignedTime = (float)timeStamps[spawnIndex];
                spawnIndex++;
            }
        }

        if (inputIndex < timeStamps.Count)
        {
            double timeStamp = timeStamps[inputIndex];
            double marginOfError = SongManager.Instance.marginOfError;
            double audioTime = SongManager.GetAudioSourceTime() - (SongManager.Instance.inputDelayInMilliseconds / 1000.0);

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(input))
            {
                if (Math.Abs(audioTime - timeStamp) < marginOfError)
                {
                    Hit();
                    print($"Perfect on {inputIndex} note");
                    Destroy(notes[inputIndex].gameObject);
                    inputIndex++;

                }
                else
                {
                    print($"Hit inaccurate on {inputIndex} note with {Math.Abs(audioTime - timeStamp)} delay");
                }
            }
            if (timeStamp + marginOfError <= audioTime)
            {
                Miss();
                print($"Missed {inputIndex} note");
                inputIndex++;
            }

        }       
    
    }
    private void Hit()
    {
        ScoreManager.Hit();
    }
    private void Miss()
    {
        ScoreManager.Miss();
    }
}
```

Comment: I seem to recall (as im not watching the tutorial) that some formats only contain notes not durations its more the note remains constant its the time between them to give an illusion. But like all those videos of marbles rolling/bouncing down xylophone blocks.